# Почему ответ сервера происходит с статусом 200 (from cache) вместо 304 (not modified) (В Chrome)

Tags: nginx, http, кэширование

**Ожидаемое поведение:** при использовании директивы `if_modified_since` в `nginx` каждый последующий запрос клиента на файл, который находится в кеше и не был изменен, будет возвращаться с статусом `304(not modified)`.

**Что происходит на самом деле:** Разное поведение для **Chrome** и **Firefox** (поведение анализирую с помощью `Dev Tools` этих браузеров). **Сhrome** возвращает статус `200(from cache)`. **Firefox** возвращает `304(Not modified)`.

Более того, при просмотре `Request Headers` в **Chrome** заголовок `if-modified-since`  не передается , в **Firefox** же этот заголовок указан. (Мне кажется, что именно запрос на сервер с этими заголовками и играет решающую роль в том, какой статус возвращается сервером).

Зайдествован сервер `nginx`.

В нем, в контексте `http {...}` я проставляю заголовки `if_modified_since before`.

И самое интересное : вне зависимости от того, какой статус пришел `200 (cache)` или `300 (not modified)` файлы **загружаются** с сервера, если были изменены.

Comment: Проверьте логи сервера. А хром вообще делал запрос?

Comment: В `Request Headers` Хрома отображается `Provisional headers are shown`

Comment: Это не логи сервера

Answer (score 0):

С 67 версии хрома в табе Network он не показывает некоторые хедеры из реквеста."Provisional headers are shown" тонкий намек на это (https://blog.ermer.de/2018/06/11/chrome-67-provisional-headers-are-shown/)

Поэтому if-modified-since может не показываться в Network, но при этом передаваться.

200 (from cache) означает, что хром взял файл из собственного кеша, не делая запрос. Это может быть из-за эвристики кеширования браузеров - если нет запрещающего кеширование хедера Cache-Control, то дисковый кеш отрабатывает, даже если нет expires хедера.

Кешируется файл на 10% с времени последнего обновления(Last-Modified-Date)
https://paulcalvano.com/index.php/2018/03/14/http-heuristic-caching-missing-cache-control-and-expires-headers-explained/

Про

> файлы загружаются с сервера, если были изменены.

от Firefox это ожидаемое поведение. Про хром сложно сказать что произошло без логов и всех хедеров, возможен вариант что как раз в это время сбросился эвристический старый кеш(т.к. 10% от последнего обновления может быть и несколько минут)